# Merging two data frames with different length and different column level in R

Tags: r

I have a problem merging two data frame with the small data frame being the priority consider the following example please:

```
d1 
x  y

a  4
b  5
c  9


d2
y  z

5  2
7  8
9  3
4  1
6  8
```

i want to get same length as the small data frame length if y column of d1 = y column of d2 as shown below:

```
merged
y  x  z

4  a  1
5  b  2
9  c  3
```

i wrote the following codes but does not seems to work:

```
merged   <- merge(d1, d2, by.x="y", by.y="y")
```

can any one help?

Thank you.

Comment: `merge(df1, df2)` should do it.  And I get the correct result with your code too.  What doesn't work about it?  What is the error message?

Comment: "Warning message: In merge.data.frame(d1, d2, by.x = "y", by.y = "y") : column name ‘y’ is duplicated in the result" and gives me "5" rows instead of 3.

Comment: @aliocee Have you tried the one RichardScriven suggested.  It should get what you wanted.  If you want to specify the `by`, it should be `merge(df1,df2, by='y')` and your codes also gives the result without any warning.  You should provide an example that gives the warning, but this does not.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the 5 rows in the output if you reverse the order of the datasets, as in:

```
merge(d2, d1, by="y")
```

You could add the additional column `z` to `d1` via:

```
d1$z<-d2$z[match(d1$y,d2$y)]
```

The warning you are getting indicates that there are columns in the two datasets with the same names, which are not not the ones you are matching on.  To see the overlap in the field names, use:

```
intersect(names(d1),names(d2))
```

(which happens to also be the default value for the argument `by`).